# Convert Unity/StructureMap interface registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, autofac

I recently switched from Unity to Autofac and am having difficulty getting my [MVC ModelMetadataFilters](https://github.com/MattHoneycutt/Fail-Tracker) dependencies to convert. These filters are all tagged with the interface `IModelMetadataFilter` and then should be injected via contructor here:

```
public ExtensibleModelMetadataProvider(IModelMetadataFilter[] metadataFilters)
{
    _metadataFilters = metadataFilters;
}
```

I have tried the code below. The `ExtensibleModelMetadataProvider` is registered, but not the `IModelMetadataFilter` classes.

```
builder.RegisterType<ExtensibleModelMetadataProvider>()
       .As<ModelMetadataProvider>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
       .Where(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IModelMetadataFilter)))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

My unity code was:

```
container.RegisterType<ModelMetadataProvider, ExtensibleModelMetadataProvider>();
container.RegisterTypes(
            AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().Where(type => typeof(IModelMetadataFilter).IsAssignableFrom(type)),
            WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
            WithName.TypeName,
            WithLifetime.Transient);
```

I had converted this from Matt Honeycutt's code below (StructureMap):

```
For<ModelMetadataProvider>().Use<ExtensibleModelMetadataProvider>();

Scan(scan =>
{
    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
    scan.AddAllTypesOf<IModelMetadataFilter>();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your use of `IsAssignableFrom` is reversed.

You should use either `typeof(IModelMetadataFilter).IsAssignableFrom(t)` or the Autofac-provided extension method `t.IsAssignableTo<IModelMetadataFilter>()` which is much more human readable.